# Discord.py card image library?

Tags: python, database, image, discord

I'm in working on a discord bot project and curious in how one of the bot in the market produce the level card for each user. Does anyone knows how to reverse engineer or maybe know how the bot that makes this card works? It does looks like an image attachment which resides on somewhere in the database but I don't know any further configurations and how this thing is made. I've tried to look for discord GUI library or anything resembles it but found nothing.

[image: one of the bot leveling card]

Comment: You should look into libraries such as [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/) for image processing which is what will be used per user to modify a base image

Comment: I've looked into one and looks like it requires a real image first as precast. How about the progress bar, should I create every possible image of the increasing progress bar or maybe there's something like DOM in python?

Comment: For DOM: It can also be done with html to png conversion which can be more powerful than pillow but also requires more setup.

Comment: @TinNguyen could you please attach some example in the answer or maybe guide me indirectly at what I should look for? I've never heard of using DOM in python and convert it to png before

Comment: You can use Jinja2 (python library) to create your html/css file. As for getting the "html to png" you will find several hits on google. e.g. https://github.com/jarrekk/imgkit. It requires knowledge of website building.

Answer (score 0):

They use discord.py api to build the bot and save ex in the database then use Pillow python library to make the Image with those data... It's easy...
Wanna know more about it?
See this GitHub repo [discord-bot-leveling-system](https://github.com/truedl/discord-bot-leveling-system)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 3yrs, but I hope your project is still up. And if you are still curious here is my solution:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from easy_pil import *

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())



@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{e}")

@bot.tree.command(name="card")
async def card(interaction:discord.Interaction,level:int,xp:int):
    background = Editor(Canvas((900, 300), color="#141414"))
    pfp = await load_image_async(str(interaction.user.avatar.url))
    profile = Editor(pfp).resize((150,150)).circle_image()

    poppins = Font.poppins(size=40)
    poppins_small = Font.poppins(size=30)

    card_right_shape = [(600,0),(750,300),(900,300),(900,0)]

    background.polygon(card_right_shape, color="#FFFFFF")
    background.paste(profile, (30, 30))

    background.rectangle((30, 220), width=650, height=40, color="#FFFFFF", radius=20,)
    background.bar((30, 220), max_width=650, height=40, percentage=xp, color="#14bed8", radius=20,)
    background.text((200, 40), interaction.user.name, font=poppins, color="#FFFFFF")

    background.rectangle((200, 100), width=350, height=2, fill="#FFFFFF")
    background.text(
        (200,130),
        f"Level - {level} | XP - {xp}/100",
        font=poppins_small,
        color="#FFFFFF",
    )

    file = discord.File(fp=background.image_bytes, filename="DCard.png")
    await interaction.response.send_message(file=file)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).